# Uniform convergence equal to pointwise convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Suppose that $h_n \to h$ pointwise and $\int_a^x \partial_x h_n (m,y) dm \to \int_a^x \partial_x h (m,y) dm$ uniformly. By FTC we know
$$
h_n(x,y) = h_n(m,y) + \int_a^x \partial_x h_n(m,y)dm.
$$
So can I deduce that
$$
h(x,y) = h(m,y) + \int_a^x \partial_x h(m,y)dm?
$$
I am confused about it since one is pointwise convergence and another is uniform convergence. How are they equal?

Comment: Hi Candlelight. Can you tell us what FTC stands for?

Comment: Hi Michael, I think it stands for Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Just fix a point $(x,y)$ and uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence. Then they are equal.